# Can I broadcast a WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have a requirement in my project to send messages on mobile phones.
I want to know whether i can do it with wcf or not and how ?
I have heard that wcf sends messages only via wires.
Please give me idea of broadcasting messages in WCF..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF doesn't really care about the transport used as long as there is an appropriate channel. Take for example the NetMsmqBinding. This uses MSMQ and not some form of direct communication.

That said broadcasting is not really a WCF capability. The closes is the peer to peer capabilities but that is not really broadcasting.